# Footer on Safari Browser Bug

Tags: html, css, typescript

I created a FrontEnd UI using **Typscript, HTML and SCSS**.  My **Header** appears to be in a **fixed position** at very top of the screen, but my **Footer changes position** when I open the UI on a **Safari Browser**. My UI(FrontEnd)Footer shows and displays correctly on other browsers like Google Chrome, Mozilla FireFox, Internet Explorer. However, **it doesn't show at the bottom of the screen on a Safari Browser**.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can target specific browser and try to fix style for that browser.
 For Safari (7+) is

`_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {
    property: value;
}`

Here you can find out how to target specific browser depending on its version: https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/

Anyway, you should post code, so we can help you better.